# Custom attribute for the title tag with wp_title()

Tags: theme-development

Can i add the `itemprop` to  the `title` element and still use `wp_head()` and `add_theme_support( "title-tag" )`?

I want to create a theme and [get it approved on wordpres.org](https://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29732#comment:23) which uses microdata.

The preceding mean i want the HTML code looks as follows:

```
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en-US">
....
        <title itemprop="name">WordPress Weblog Theme &#8211; Just another WordPress site</title>
....
```

Now i do not use `add_theme_support( "title-tag" )` and use the following code in header.php?

```
<title itemprop="name"><?php echo wp_get_document_title(); ?></title>
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

Now the theme check plugin says:

> REQUIRED: The theme needs to have a call to wp_title(), ideally in the
>   header.php file. REQUIRED: The theme needs to have  tags,
>   ideally in the header.php file. RECOMMENDED: No reference to
>   add_theme_support( "title-tag" ) was found in the theme. It is
>   recommended that the theme implement this functionality for WordPress
>   4.1 and above.

Comment: so you can just do `<title itemprop="name"><?php wp_title(); ?></title>`?

Comment: @majick Not if you want to go the way WP is recommending with adding theme support for built in title tags

Comment: A workaround  could be to unhook `_wp_render_title_tag` from the `wp_head` and hook instead a custom version of `_wp_render_title_tag` with the title attribute, but I don't think that would be considered best practice for a public theme ;-)

Comment: @birgire workarounds that make it possible to achieve what you desire *are* best practice when compared to "you can't do that" - you should post that as an answer because it is the solution. :-)

Comment: that's a valid point @majick but I don't know if it would pass the wordpress.org theme review ;-) Maybe I will post it as an alternative workaround later today, ;-)

Comment: well technically my solution would pass as it is `recommended` but not required, but yours is better because it does mesh with the preferred practice, so can't see a reason it would be refused, especially if a trac ticket is opened for it in the meanwhile.

Comment: If we're gonna cheat I suggest putting `wp_head` in an output buffer and do a `str_replace` before flushing it. ;-)

Comment: @cjnbj ha well that is a lot of scope, I have just posted a tighter solution along those lines. :-)

Comment: Should we make a trac for this one? The html5 specs allow aria roles for the title tag and its strange WP wouldn't support that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all `_wp_render_title_tag` does is check for `title-tag` theme support and wrap in `<title>` tags, there is really no reason why your existing implementation "shall not pass", since the proper implementation is already identical via:

```
<title itemprop="name"><?php echo wp_get_document_title(); ?></title>
```

when `_wp_render_title_tag` does:

```
echo '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n";
```

(since Theme Check is a guideline check, so what if it can't tell that a standard actually has been followed, that should in theory not stop it from passing?)

But in any case, you *can* get around this *and* improve the existing implementation at the same time by adding a customization override filter... by unhooking the existing action (as suggested by @birgire) and (my addition) hooking a wrapping function that calls `_wp_render_title_tag` and applies the filter to it:

```
if (has_action('wp_head','_wp_render_title_tag') == 1) {
    remove_action('wp_head','_wp_render_title_tag',1);
    add_action('wp_head','custom_wp_render_title_tag_filtered',1);
}

function custom_wp_render_title_tag_filtered() {
    if (function_exists('_wp_render_title_tag')) {
        ob_start(); 
        _wp_render_title_tag(); 
        $titletag = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    } else {$titletag = '';}
    return apply_filters('wp_render_title_tag_filter',$titletag);
}
```

Since it's better practice to have a filter available anyway....... Then you can add your own use case customizations easily by using the new filter:

```
add_filter('wp_render_title_tag_filter','custom_wp_render_title_tag');

function custom_wp_render_title_tag($titletag) {
    $titletag = str_replace('<title>','<title itemprop="name">',$titletag);
    return $titletag;
}
```

Of course it would be much cleaner if the core function was simply updated to:

```
function _wp_render_title_tag() {
    if ( ! current_theme_supports( 'title-tag' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    echo apply_filters( 'wp_render_title_tag' , '<title>' . wp_get_document_title() . '</title>' . "\n" );
}
```

Comment: +1 for being a smartass, but I still wouldn't recommend doing it like this in a public theme, because it is not future proof. WP might change the workings of the private function and the theme could break.

Comment: you're right could be a little better there... I updated the code to add filter priority match and function check, unique function names... apart from that I don't see how a passthrough function wrapper like this could break anything... as an override it will either be triggered or not...

Comment: Since `wp_head` is an action, we could use `has_action` for that context, even though it's just a wrapper for `has_filter`  ;-)

Comment: i see you ran `has_typo` on the code... fixed. ;-)

Comment: This is not working anymore (as of WordPress 4.8). The `<title>` tag gets removed completely.

Comment: still working for me in 4.8, is there something you can point to that is different for you?

Comment: The `remove_action('wp_head','_wp_render_title_tag',1)` is working with Wordpress latest release i.e 4.9.2

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately echoing the `<title>` tag is currently hardwired in [`general-template.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/general-template.php) (line 1062). It's in a private function, meaning that you cannot modify or overrule it. So, at the moment you cannot modify the tag. You might want to issue a [trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/) to ask that they support this in the future.

Comment: but but... the impossible is achieved by those who think it possible... :-)