# How to modify files inside wp-includes directory in wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, functions, customization, child-theme, core-modifications

I want to modify `wp-includes/general-template.php`

```
function _wp_render_title_tag() {}
```

Need to allow some limit to title tag,
if title of the page will be more than 10 character then it should be shown only 5 characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/228183/94498

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't recommending any core files.

Instead, you can filter the title and make your changes, like so:

```
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title ) ) {
  // $title is an array of parts

  if ( strlen( $title['title'] ) > 10 ) {
    $title['title'] = substr( $title['title'], 0, 5 ); // Show only first 5 characters
  }

  return $title;
}, 10, 1 );
```