# How do I change the <title> element using a custom function?

Tags: customization, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I am trying to add meta titles via the Yoast SEO plugin.

My theme is not compatible with this -- the resulting `<title>` tag is a concatenation of the Yoast title and the theme's title.

One solution is to ensure the `<title>` tag in `header.php` is set to `<?php wp_title(''); ?>` (see [Yoast article here](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/the-seo-title-output-for-the-plugin-doesnt-work-as-expected/) -- section "Themes without title-tag Support").

This method works (I tested it), and is also the solution suggested to me by my theme devs. But how can I do this via a custom function in my child theme's functions.php, rather than editing header.php?

I realize one possible solution is to copy header.php from parent theme to child theme, then edit that file. But I’m trying to avoid that if possible.

I tried the answer given in [this previous question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274429/how-do-i-edit-the-title-tag-without-using-the-deprecated-wp-title-function), but all that did was add a second `<title>` tag to the page, in addition to the existing, incorrect `<title>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an incorrect `<title>` tag has been added to the header *template* the only option that will work is the child theme method. You can't override template markup with a custom function.

If you do use a child theme then don't use `wp_title()`, just remove the title tag entirely and register support for support [`title-tag`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Title_Tag).

Comment: Thanks for that.  When you say, "You can't override template markup with a custom function," you are speaking in reference to the the `<title>` tag only--correct?  Also, when you say, "If you do use a child theme then don't use wp_title(), just remove the title tag entirely and register support for support title-tag," that still requires me to edit header.php in my child theme--correct?

Comment: "you are speaking in reference to the the <title> tag only--correct?" 
No. It's a general rule. You can change the outputs of functions that have a filter, or replace the template in a child theme, but you can't use a function to change arbitrary bits of markup within a template.
"that still requires me to edit header.php in my child theme--correct?" Yes, to remove the title tag.

Comment: "You can change the outputs of functions that have a filter"  Got it.  It was this that I just wanted to confirm was still possible.  "you can't use a function to change arbitrary bits of markup within a template."  Got it--that's what I'm trying to do here.  I was hoping `<title>` was a special case, that perhaps had some special WordPress API function to arbitrarily modify it.  Wishful thinking I guess.  OK thanks for the explanation.